# How to add error bars to a Data Frame Grouped bar plot or even an array of arrays grouped bar plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, plot

I'm having some trouble getting error bars on a grouped bar plot I have to make and after spending several days trying to figure out how to do so, I think it's time to ask the experts here for some help (pretty please!)

After doing calculations, sorting, and data reduction, I've posted the plotting portion of the code below.  It runs, and you can cut and paste it into your favorite editor.  I want to add error bars to the df plot using the values either in df2 or e1.  I'm not married to the idea of doing this as a Data Frame plot, but it's the only way I was able to get the bar plots to plot in a group format.  Can someone who knows Python better than I do help with getting the grouped plot with error bars added from the data included below.  I am grateful for any help anyone can provide!  :-)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *

opacity = 0.6

Measured = (1010, 1119, 1124, 1852, 1862, 876, 889, 891, 873, 873, 872, 1900, 1890, 1901)

C = (80,70,70,70,70,70)

myarray = [[1009, 1010],
 [1122, 1119, 1124],
 [1842, 1852, 1862],
 [881, 876, 889, 891],
 [880, 873, 873, 872],
 [1890, 1900, 1890, 1901]]

e1 = [[4.3, 16.4],
 [4.6, 16.8, 16.2],
 [11.4, 14.3, 14.2],
 [3.7, 11.4, 11.6, 11.6],
 [3.9, 16.7, 17.2, 16.6],
 [8.3, 13.4, 13.9, 13.6]]



length = len(sorted(myarray,key=len, reverse=True)[0])
s=np.array([myarrayi+[None]*(length-len(myarrayi)) for myarrayi in myarray])

length2 = len(sorted(e1,key=len, reverse=True)[0])
e2=np.array([e1i+[None]*(length2-len(e1i)) for e1i in e1])

df = pd.DataFrame(s, columns=['Theo.', 'Exp1', 'Exp2', 'Exp3']) #DataFrame of the Theoritical and experimental values
df2 = pd.DataFrame(e1, columns=['Theo.', 'Exp1', 'Exp2', 'Exp3']) #DataFrame of the error that I wan to add as error bars to the first data frame
df.plot(kind='bar', color=['r', 'b', 'b', 'b'], alpha = opacity)

plt.xlim([0, len(C)+0.25]) 
plt.ylim([min(Measured)-500, max(Measured)+200]) # Uses the min and max values of the matrix elements to set the axis boundaries so the scaling is the same all of the time
xlabel("Theoretical vs Experimental Values")
ylabel("Arbitrary units")
title('Comparison Data Grouped Plots', color='#000000', fontsize=18)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone else ever searches for this particular issue, I wanted to post the solution that finally worked.  Apparently, in earlier versions of Pandas (0.013.1 was what I was previously using) there was an issue with trying to to what I was attempting to do with the second data frame.  In 0.15, it seems to work now!  So, for completeness, here's the code that I was able to use to plot grouped bar plots with associated errors for each individual measurement value:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *

opacity = 0.6

Measured = (1010, 1119, 1124, 1852, 1862, 876, 889, 891, 873, 873, 872, 1900, 1890, 1901)

C = (80,70,70,70,70,70)

myarray = [[1009, 1010],
 [1122, 1119, 1124],
 [1842, 1852, 1862],
 [881, 876, 889, 891],
 [880, 873, 873, 872],
 [1890, 1900, 1890, 1901]]

e1 = [[4.3, 16.4],
 [4.6, 16.8, 16.2],
 [11.4, 14.3, 14.2],
 [3.7, 11.4, 11.6, 11.6],
 [3.9, 16.7, 17.2, 16.6],
 [8.3, 13.4, 13.9, 13.6]]

length = len(sorted(myarray,key=len, reverse=True)[0])
s=np.array([myarrayi+[None]*(length-len(myarrayi)) for myarrayi in myarray])

length2 = len(sorted(e1,key=len, reverse=True)[0])
e2=np.array([e1i+[None]*(length2-len(e1i)) for e1i in e1])

df = pd.DataFrame(s, columns=['Theo', 'Exp1', 'Exp2', 'Exp3']) #DataFrame of the Theoritical and experimental values
df2 = pd.DataFrame(e1, columns=['Theo', 'Exp1', 'Exp2', 'Exp3']) #DataFrame of the error that I wan to add as error bars to the first data frame
df[['Theo', 'Exp1', 'Exp2', 'Exp3']].plot(kind='bar', yerr=df2[['Theo', 'Exp1', 'Exp2', 'Exp3']].values.T, color=['r', 'b', 'b', 'b'], alpha = opacity,error_kw=dict(ecolor='k'))


plt.xlim([-.5, len(C)-.5]) 
plt.ylim([min(Measured)-500, max(Measured)+200]) # Uses the min and max values of the matrix elements to set the axis boundaries so the scaling is the same all of the time
xlabel("Theoretical vs Experimental Values")
ylabel("Arbitrary units")
title('Comparison Data Grouped Plots', color='#000000', fontsize=18)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```